# Convert Java to C# (Unity)

Tags: java, c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to convert [this Java code](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/43stack/Evaluate.java.html) (Evaluates arithmetic expressions using Dijkstra's two-stack algorithm) to C# :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public class Evaluate
{
    public double Eval(string expression)
    {
        Stack<string> ops = new Stack<string>();
        Stack<double> vals = new Stack<double>();

        string s = expression;
        while (!s.Equals(""))
        {
            if (s.Equals("(")) ;
            if (s.Equals("+")) ops.Push(s);
            else if (s.Equals("-")) ops.Push(s);
            else if (s.Equals("*")) ops.Push(s);
            else if (s.Equals("/")) ops.Push(s);
            else if (s.Equals("sqrt")) ops.Push(s);
            else if (s.Equals(")"))
            {
                string op = ops.Pop();
                double v = vals.Pop();
                if (op.Equals("+")) v = vals.Pop() + v;
                else if (op.Equals("-")) v = vals.Pop() - v;
                else if (op.Equals("*")) v = vals.Pop() * v;
                else if (op.Equals("/")) v = vals.Pop() / v;
                else if (op.Equals("sqrt")) v = Math.Sqrt(v);
                vals.Push(v);
            }
            else vals.Push(double.Parse(s));
        }
        return vals.Pop();
    }
}
```

But Unity stop working when I'm try to test it. What have I done wrong?

Comment: at a very brief glance, it appears you never re-assign `s`, and you loop indefinitely.

Comment: In what way does it "stop working"?  When you step through this in a debugger, where/how exactly does it fail?

Comment: Are you calling it inside a MonoBehaviour Update function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is behaving as expected. You did not translate the Java code to C# well. I can spot one problem for now but I don't know if there is more of them when you fix this one.

The Java original code **exits** the while loop if input is **empty**. Below is what the Java code looks like:

```
while (!StdIn.isEmpty()) {
String s = StdIn.readString();  
......
......
}
```

It uses the **input** to **break** out of the while loop. Exits if input is empty.

Your  C# code:

```
while (!s.Equals(""))
{
......
......
}
```

It uses **s** to **break** out of the while loop but **s** is not being changed any where in the loop. So the loop keeps going.This leads to infinite loop and infinite loop in Unity **=** Lock/Freeze with few Exceptions.

Fix **#1**. Call  Eval in another Thread. Not recommended for a beginner.

Fix **#2**. Use **Coroutine**.

My solution is with Coroutine.

Change your function return type from `double` to `Coroutine` then put  `yield return null;` inside the `while` loop. To **call** the function, use  `StartCoroutine(Eval("Your Expression"));`. The use of `yield return null;` will **prevent** Unity from crashing.

Even when you do this, you code still won't exit when you pass in a value that is not empty but it **wont** **Lock**/**Freeze** anymore.

To fix this and replicate the code from Java, you should find a way to exit the program with an input.

Go to **GameObject**->**UI**->**Input Field** and Rename that **GameObject** to **EvalInput**;

Now use the Input field and the code below to make the C# code look and function more like the Java Code. The final result is stored in the global `evalResult` variable.

```
InputField evalInput;
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(Eval("Your Expression"));
    evalInput = GameObject.Find("EvalInput").GetComponent<InputField>();
}

double evalResult = 0;
public IEnumerator Eval(string expression)
{
    Stack<string> ops = new Stack<string>();
    Stack<double> vals = new Stack<double>();
    string s = expression;
    while (!s.Equals(""))
    {
        s = evalInput.text; //Modify the string here (Empty string == Exit)

        if (s.Equals("(")) ;
        if (s.Equals("+")) ops.Push(s);
        else if (s.Equals("-")) ops.Push(s);
        else if (s.Equals("*")) ops.Push(s);
        else if (s.Equals("/")) ops.Push(s);
        else if (s.Equals("sqrt")) ops.Push(s);
        else if (s.Equals(")"))
        {
            string op = ops.Pop();
            double v = vals.Pop();
            if (op.Equals("+")) v = vals.Pop() + v;
            else if (op.Equals("-")) v = vals.Pop() - v;
            else if (op.Equals("*")) v = vals.Pop() * v;
            else if (op.Equals("/")) v = vals.Pop() / v;
            else if (op.Equals("sqrt")) v = System.Math.Sqrt(v);
            vals.Push(v);
        }
        else vals.Push(double.Parse(s));

        yield return null;
    }
    evalResult = vals.Pop();
}
```

Comment: Error : `FormatException: Unknown char: (
System.Double.Parse (System.String s, NumberStyles style, IFormatProvider provider)`

Comment: @ARTAGE. My answer will solve your freezing problem and also provide a way to use input just like the Java code. Just like I mentioned in the beginning of it, I don't know if that is the only problem in the code. You can ask another question if you are still having problems just like the error above.